# where could we get these latex books as ebook not paperbook?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pstricks

1. PSTricks Graphics and PostScript for TeX and LaTeX, Herbert Voss (Autor)
2. The LaTeX Graphics Companion 2nd edition

Comment: latex companion from https://www.informit.com/store/latex-companion-9780201362992?ranMID=24808

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  thanks in advance, but am looking for The LaTeX Graphics Companion not The LaTeX Companion

Comment: I don't think the graphics companion is available https://www.pearson.ch/Informatik/Addison-Wesley/EAN/9780321508928/LaTeX-Graphics-Companion-The